# Where can I buy Light Armor training?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been leveling as a thief for quite a while, and I now need to use some of this ill-gotten booty (or maybe that's ill-booten gotty) to bring some of my combat skills up to par.  I know there's an expert One-Hand trainer from the Companion's Guild, but I don't believe I've found a Light Armor trainer yet, can anyone direct me to them?

Comment: Nazir from the Dark Brotherhood trains Light Armor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The journeyman Light Armor trainer is **Scouts-Many-Marshes** in Windhelm.

The expert trainer is **Grelka** in Riften. You can find her in the marketplace.

Finally, the master trainer is **Nazir** found only in the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary, in the southern part of Falkreath Hold. Unless you've completed the Dark Brotherhood questline, and the Sanctuary has been relocated.

Answer (score 0):

Nazir. just do the dark brotherhood quest it gives you a nice set of light armor and if you get the fourtane teller token thing for doing it right you can get some ancient shrouded armor

Comment: It actually answers the question... poorly. Nazir is a light armor training you get access to from the dark brotherhood quest.